# Is there any function to generate unique numbers

Tags: database

Hello I have a table by the name of images which is storing the ImageID, images folder 
path and Images name. For holding these images a folder is going to be created 
automatically while uploading by The mkdir () function and taking its name from rand () function.

problem is whenever I’m using Rand() for naming my images folder it’s repeating.
Means the rand() is generating repeated numbers what I should do to be unique? 
Actually the Image ID is the name of the folder which is primary key which is not 
accepting repeated values and I also need unique values.

Is there any other function to be used to generate unique numbers?

Comment: What programming language are you using? You may need to seed the random number generator.

Comment: Maybe a hash would be applicable? The idea being that, for something like SHA that the chance of a collision is too unlikely to care about. (An HMAC can be used to reduce the chance of being able to exploit "known" hashes, and SHA can be easily ramped from 160 to 256+.) Alternatively, a UUIDv4 might be an option - the idea is the same, but it would be independent of the data itself.

Comment: thnx for reply i m using PHP

Comment: you can also use Current Date Time(MMDDYYYYHHmmss) as unique number..that will never repeat

Comment: the folder name can not accept the times stamp cause its using slashes as i am think

Comment: Why not keep the image ID as the folder name? If this is unique in your database then the folder name should also be unique? Unless you are trying to create more random folder names and keep these unique... Could you update your question to give us a bit more information as to what you want to do?

Comment: @user3624731 Dates don't need slashes in them..

Comment: @Big chris:  Folder Name is equal to ImageID

Comment: Ok. Whoops! Why not keep this, then? Your process should be to create your database entry first, when this is successful you can create your directory. Using MySQLi or PDO you can now get the last created record ID (your image ID) and immediately use this as the new folder name...?

Comment: @BigChris: recently i have started using php so im beginer and i have not used PDO

Comment: You need to use one or the other - I prefer PDO as you can use named parameters a bit more easily than MySQLi. Don't use 'mysql_' (old MySQL) commands...

Answer (score 0):

Folder name should not be unique. So alter the table and make the file name as unique. You can update a unique value but should not add again.